# How to delete a field from field collection programmatically?

Tags: entities

I am using Drupal 7.2. I have to delete a field from a field collection programmatically.
is there any function which can be used to delete it?

Comment: You should have added the answer separately.

Comment: Rollback to revision without answer. Please add answer as an answer. If anyone needs to know answer before it will be posted, it is in [this revision](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/89192/2).